# Run out or end?

Tags: word-usage

Suppose you are eating something, a soup for instance, you're not finding particularly enjoyable. What do you think you might find yourself saying afterwards: "that soup never seemed to end" or "that soup never seemed to run out?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"That bowl of soup seemed bottomless!"

Comment: What if it wasn't a soup and it was a pie or cookies?

Comment: That pie never seemed to end is OK!

Those cookies never ran out!

I have a slight feeling that running out is better applied to things where there is some mystery as to their source, such as cookies taken from an opaque packet.

Getting very deep into this now, though!

Comment: On a side note: would it be fine to say "the pie ended?"
Thanks for taking the time to reply, for some reason I can't wrap my head around this.

Comment: No.  "I finished the pie" is OK, though, or maybe "the pie was finished", or "I finished off the pie".  They all mean basically the same thing!

Comment: Good way to phrase it.  Though I am curious if there is an expression that also incorporates the negative connotation mentioned in the original question, i.e. The reason the bowl seemed bottomless is because it was not "particularly enjoyable", as opposed to there being so much soup on hand, the bowl seemed bottomless.